# creating statement from While loop and print

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, printing

Good day. Im a few days old in coding and Im not sure if what Im trying to create is impossible or not but please help if you can.

When running this statement:

```py
i = 1
while i < 20:
  print(i)
  i += 1
```

numbers are printed by a list. `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19`.

I want to create a single number which is a combination of the past 2 printed numbers + the current one and assign it the letter `a` at each turn. For example, after `1` is printed the are no past 2 numbers so `a = invalid` after `2` is printed `a = invalid` because there are no 2 past printed numbers,  after `3` is printed, `a=123`. After `4` is printed, `a = 234`. After `5` is printed, `a=345` and so on.

> I decided  to go with the method that stores the results instead of the solutions that depend on arithmetic because my actual problems is not the same as that I wrote here.

```js
i = 1    
number_store = []   
while i<10:   
       number_store.append(i)   
       if len(number_store) ==4:    
       del number_store[0]   
       print(number_store)    
       i +=1
```

Thank you to everyone who answered

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Create a list, push the current number at the end, if the size is larger than three, pop an element from the beginning.

Comment: You could either calculate the last numbers, e.g. `i - 1` or you could save them in variables e.g. `last1 = i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to store the 3 numbers in a list.
At each loop (turn) the new number would be added to the list, like so `stored_numbers.append(str(i))`
And if the list becomes longer than 3 elements, you delete the first element like so

```
if len(stored_numbers) == 4:
    del stored_numbers(0)
```

You can then print the concatenated list with `print(''.join(stored_numbers))`

However, since your example only calls for incrementation by 1, then you can get away with some arithmetic

```
i = 3
while i < 20:
    print((i-2)*100+(i-1)*10+i)
    i += 1
```

The `while` loop you use can be expressed more pythonically as a for loop, like this

```
for i in range(3,21):
    print((i-2)*100+(i-1)*10+i)
    # i += 1  /No need for this, since i is incremented by the for loop
```

Comment: Thank you llia for your answer. Unfortunately my up vote cant be recorded since i still have a less than 15 reputation to show my appreciation. One question though, the code you have given me to print the concatenated list returns error: "sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found"

Comment: Right. I should have turned the numbers into strings first. Let me edit the answer (see the first code line, the one where we append to the list)

Comment: Ohh thank you again. Just did as you said and it turned out perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [f strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to format the result:

```
i = 1
past = 2

while i < 20:
    if i > past:
        print(f'{i-2}{i-1}{i}')
    i += 1
```

Out:

```
123
234
345
456
567
678
789
8910
91011
101112
111213
121314
131415
141516
151617
161718
171819
```

Answer (score 0):

Here arr will contain all the contents you need

```
arr=[]
i=1
while i<20:
    if (i-2<=0):
        a="invalid"
        print(a)
        arr.append(a)
        i=i+1
    else:
        a=str(i-2)+str(i-1)+str(i)
        arr.append(a)
        i=i+1

print(arr)
```